# targetinvocationexception was unhandled when using async web service

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I'm not able to catch an error (`targetinvocationexception` was unhandled)

I have a webservice client class:

```
Partial Public Class NfeAutorizacao
        Inherits System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
```

etc..

I call the webservice async:

```
Public Overloads Sub nfeAutorizacaoLoteAsync(ByVal nfeDadosMsg As
                     System.Xml.XmlNode, ByVal userState As Object)

  If (Me.nfeAutorizacaoLoteOperationCompleted Is Nothing) Then
    Me.nfeAutorizacaoLoteOperationCompleted =
       AddressOf Me.OnnfeAutorizacaoLoteOperationCompleted
  End If
  Me.InvokeAsync("nfeAutorizacaoLote", New Object() {nfeDadosMsg},
                 Me.nfeAutorizacaoLoteOperationCompleted, userState)
End Sub
```

If there is no internet an exception is thrown which I'm unable to catch. So my application crashes.

What am I doing wrong; is there a way to catch the error?

Comment: Is the exception being thrown from here, or from the callback function (not shown)?  Where/how do you try to catch the exception?

Comment: what (value) is returned if no internet is present?

Comment: Thanks as soon as I call the async method the error is thrown and I can't catch it.

Comment: this is the exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.